# How to display 'Shipping & Handling' in PDF if Shipping Amount is $0.00?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, orders, invoice, pdf

**Magento 2.3.2**

In my invoice PDF if Shipping & Handling amount is null or 0 it hides that row like this:

[image]

But I want to to display it as `$0.00` if the price is null like this:

[image]

I found this file `/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/DefaultTotal.php`, in this file there is a function `canDisplay()` which is responsible for hiding the Title and Amount from Total section in invoice PDF. so I did some changes in function to display `Shipping and Handling` if it's `$0.00`:

```
public function canDisplay()
{   
    $amount = $this->getAmount();

    /* TO DISPLAY SHIPPING & HANDLING IN INVOICE PDF IF ITS $0.00 - PARTAB SAIFUDDIN */
    if(strtolower($this->getTitle()) == "shipping & handling" && $amount == 0){
        return true;
    }

    return $this->getDisplayZero() === 'true' || $amount != 0;
}
```

and I got the result as I want, but when I override this file it didn't work and I find out that "Shipping & Handling" doesn't exist in `echo $this->getTitle()`, these are the titles which I got in a file which I override:

```
Discount
Adjustment Refund
Adjustment Fee
```

and these are the titles which I got in core file:

```
Subtotal
Tax
Shipping & Handling
Grand Total
```

I don't understand why I'm not getting "Shipping & Handling" in my overridden file...

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest, using the XML approach here instead of an override, as overrides can easily break things and create incompatibilities.
In `vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/pdf.xml` we find the following code block:

```
        <total name="shipping">
            <title translate="true">Shipping &amp; Handling</title>
            <source_field>shipping_amount</source_field>
            <font_size>7</font_size>
            <display_zero>false</display_zero>
            <sort_order>400</sort_order>
        </total>
```

The interesting part here is the `<display_zero>` node, which is also used by default in the `canDisplay()` function.
So to solve that problem, I created a custom module which requires `Magento_Sales` and add an own `pdf.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <totals>
        <total name="shipping">
            <display_zero>true</display_zero>
        </total>
    </totals>
</config>
```

This displays the shipping amount regardless of the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue is resolved, there is a file `/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/Sales/Pdf/Shipping.php`, I override this file and add `canDisplay()` function in it:

```
public function canDisplay()
{
    $amount = $this->getAmount();
    /* TO DISPLAY SHIPPING & HANDLING IN INVOICE PDF IF ITS $0.00 - PARTAB SAIFUDDIN */
    if(strtolower($this->getTitle()) == "shipping & handling" && $amount == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return $this->getDisplayZero() === 'true' || $amount != 0;
}
```

and I get result as I want:

[image]